# Undefined value returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple Stripe form that contains just some random value right now and I'm trying to grab that value but when I place it in a `console.log` it's returning an undefined value although there's one there. I've tried several solutions, but they simply haven't worked. I'm trying to just grab the text of 'work'. Anyone have a clue to whats going on?

**HTML - Head**

```
<head>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
```

**HTML - Form**

```
<body>

<h3 id="work" value="400">500</h3>

<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">

    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>

    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
    <div id="card-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
</body>
```

**This is also located within my one HTML file as the form:**

```
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

card.mount('#card-element');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  ...
});

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  ...
});

function stripeTokenHandler(token) {

  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  var totalAmount = document.createElement('input');

  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);

  totalAmount.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  totalAmount.setAttribute('name', 'totalAmount');
  totalAmount.setAttribute('value', $('#work').innerHTML); //<-- Trying to get the value here

  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  form.appendChild(totalAmount);
  console.log(totalAmount);

  var formData = JSON.stringify({
    mytoken: token.id,
    totalAmount: totalAmount.value
  });

  console.log(formData); //<-- showing that it's undefined

  $.ajax({
    ...
  });

  // form.submit();
}
</script>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: You do not need to use the setAttribute method. It is easier to write ist like that: hiddenInput.type = 'hidden';  hiddenInput.name = 'stripeToken'; hiddentInput.value = token.id; ...

Comment: document.getElementById('work').innerHTML  would work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#work').innerHTML
```

To this:

```
$('#work').html()
```

If you want to use innerHTML from a JQuery object, you can use the following:

```
$('#work')[0].innerHTML
```

or pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById('work').innerHTML
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: You didn't see my answer ?

Comment: @YouneL I think you've answered while I'm writing mime :-)

Comment: personally when I see someone post an answer before me, I stopped, especially if it was the same idea

Comment: You didn't see my previous comment?  Additionally, your answer has only a part of mime, so, these answers will help the OP and the community.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method since you are using jquery `$` selector:

```
$('#work').text()
```

In native javascript:

```
document.getElementById('work').innerText
```